# I’m a little slow to process my thinking, but rather than just telling people I’m a bit slow I would like something witty to say

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Anyone got anything witty to say as if I was sort of saying I’m a bit slow in a witty way or a self respectful way but with a bit a humour, sort of like in a melancholic self depreciating way and  fashion, thanks

Comment: "I'm experiencing a bit of time dilation".  Works only if your listener understands a bit of Special Relativity and isn't going to spoil it by commenting  that you are at rest with respect to each other.

Comment: +1.  I like this question.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this lovely catalog : https://dan.hersam.com/lists/not_bright.html

Not all of these are equally respectful, here's a sample of what I feel come off as both witty and appropriate:

> A few watts short of a light bulb
>
> Not the quickest bunny in the forest
>
> A few needles short of a sewing kit
>
> Running on 3 cylinders

Comment: I love that catalog. My favourite is probably "I forgot to pay my brain bill". I am using that one from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can hint that you are not very alert at that moment by claiming that you are ***in a fog***.

> Sorry, but I am ***in a fog*** at the moment, so I'd appreciate if you can
>   repeat that.

TFD(idioms):

> **[in a fog](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+a+fog)**
>
> Not fully aware or alert; having one's attention clouded with
>   something.
>
> I always feel like I'm in a fog when I take that medication. It's like
>   it's hard for me to think.
>
> Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2015 Farlex, Inc, all rights reserved.

Answer (score 0):

How about ‘sorry, I’m running on an earlier version of software, and I need a moment to process what you’re saying’.

I do also love to say, ironically, in situations where things are going a bit slow ‘turn the handle faster, Igor - the creature is reviving!’ Which is from some old black and white Frankenstein movie, where the assistant, Igor is being called upon to turn the crank more quickly (in order to apply the electricity to Frankenstein’s monster) - so that the monster... will wake up.